# replace nested object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I've this object called

`const formValues = {...}`

inside this object we have an array, this value must have one element or more,

```
formValues: { 
    locations: [...];
}
```

inside the array `locations` we have multiple values: strings and objects.

```
formValues: { 
    locations: [
        key1: string
        key2: string
        key3: object
        key4: string
        key5: object
        key6: string
        key7: object
    ];
}
```

How can i convert the `key5` to an array ?

i already tried using the `map` of lodash, but it doesn't work because at some point it generates a double array in the `key5` ( `key5: [[...]]` )

```
const newFormValues = map(formValues, item =>
    map(item, el => ({
      ...el,
      workHours: [el.workHours],
    })),
  );

 const data = {
    data: { locations: flatten(newFormValues) },
    section: 'locations',
    confirm,
  };
```

***EXPECTED RESULT***

The same object

```
formValues: { 
    locations: [
        key1: string
        key2: string
        key3: object
        key4: string
        key5: **array**
        key6: string
        key7: object
    ];
}
```

but the **key5** must be an array instead of an object

Comment: Please post actual (working) input and the expected output.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking but try: `workHours: [].concat(el.workHours)`. This will work when `el.workHours` is an object or an array

Comment: @adiga, yes you are right. can you post your answer ? it's the correct one.

Comment: I've closed it as duplicate since the questions are similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Object.entries(the_object)
```

For example if the object is

```
var theObject = {a: 1, b: 2};
Object.entries(theObject)
```

gives you the result 
     [ ["a", 1], ["b", 2]]

Comment: thank you for the answer, i'm trying your advice, i will update the post soon :)

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: but how array look like? you can describe more details how it look like currently and how it look like as an expected result